# Вызов Joomla-вых редакторов в моем модуле

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вызвать редактор джумлы в моем модуле и что бы я мог отлавливать с него данные в базу и выводить на него данные в мною созданной отдельной админке.

Comment: какая версия Joomla! ?

Comment: 3.6.5-версия Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используйте Joomla 3 линейки, можете вызвать редактор так:

```
/* В первую очередь подключаем */
jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );

/* Получаем редактор с параметрами (которые можно установить в админке) */
$editor = JEditor::getInstance(JFactory::getUser()->getParam("editor"));

/* Выводим редактор в нужном месте*/
echo $editor->display('content', $DBcontent, '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
```

Параметр `content` -> под данным значением будет отправляться информация через `POST`

`$DBcontent` - в данной переменой должен находиться контент который получаете из базы, для показа и редактирования.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне пишет что:"Не удалось отобразить редактор, потому что не опубликован ни один плагин редактора."

Comment: у вас отключён редактор ? зайдите в Глобальные настройки в админке, найдите пункт  (смотри ссылку http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/edu/joomla-3/global-configuration/default-editor-settings.gif)
что у вас там показывает ?